# Routing a specific domain or range through a PPTP VPN and all others through direct connection in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, vpn, routing

How can I route *.website/* through a PPTP VPN, while keeping all other traffic going through my default connection?

I have tried using the [Switchy! Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/caehdcpeofiiigpdhbabniblemipncjj), but all my traffic is still being routed through the VPN. I have also tried using Switchy! with *Use default gateway on remote network* un-checked, in VPN Properties > TCP/IPvX Properties > Advanced, but then no traffic goes through the VPN.

**ipconfig:**

```
Windows IP Configuration


PPP adapter <VPN Name>:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 109.203.119.53
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f8fe:cca1:f3a3:f48d%14
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.126
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::7d4a:26c7:5008:2cde%13
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.124
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:5ef5:79fb:3c45:35a8:9234:88ca
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3c45:35a8:9234:88ca%17
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{CF1CF9B1-F6D9-47FF-AB7F-63ECE409865A}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{A018F93F-B08C-411E-B52E-03F2CFA36A3F}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{927612C5-79AA-4B27-9720-0CBA1CEE015C}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter 6TO4 Adapter:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2002:6dcb:7359::6dcb:7359
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2002:6dcb:7735::6dcb:7735
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 2002:c058:6301::c058:6301

Tunnel adapter isatap.{003D0641-570E-4AE8-A12F-EAC232330F4D}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{495074FD-C55E-42EA-8705-A55DCFD7DA4A}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{D608462A-2194-412E-AB3F-A3DA331EB260}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{5E4A9EE1-6034-4A27-8E83-CE8F30B38036}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

**route print 0:**

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 45...........................<VPN Name>
 41...00 ff d6 08 46 2a ......TAP-Win32 Adapter V9
 16...c4 85 08 11 c5 1b ......Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter #2
 15...c4 85 08 11 c5 1b ......Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
 14...c4 85 08 11 c5 1a ......Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6235
 13...e8 03 9a ad 60 45 ......Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
 12...c4 85 08 11 c5 1e ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 17...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 20...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 21...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 19...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
 18...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft 6to4 Adapter
 39...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #6
 40...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #7
 44...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #8
 46...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #9
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.124   4236
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         On-link    109.203.119.53     11
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
  None
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

EDIT: The VPN service I am using also has an OpenVPN server. Would my goal be possible using an OpenVPN client?